# Join three tables to get matched and unmatched data

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have below 3 tables.

Table 1: Invoice

Columns - ID,SPENT,ROLEID

```
ID | SPENT | ROLEID

1  | 500   |  1
2  | 400   |  2
```

Table 2: ROLES

Columns - ROLE_ID (PK),DEPARTMENT_ID,ROLE_NAME

```
ROLE_ID | DEPARTMENT_ID | ROLE_NAME

1       |    1          | AGENT
2       |    2          | SUPERVISOR
```

Table 3: DEPARTMENT

Columns - DEP_ID,DEP_NAME

```
DEP_ID | DEP_NAME

1   | ACCOUNTING 
2   | CUSTOMER_SERVICE
3   | HRA
```

The final output is that if I look for the invoices, I should see all the departments even when I just got  a invoices for 1 department.

Below is the query which I tried.

```
SELECT
       D.DEP_NAME
      ,I.SPENT
FROM INVOICE I 
CROSS JOIN DEPARTMENT D
LEFT JOIN ROLES R ON R.ROLE_ID = I.ROLE_ID AND D.DEP_ID = R.DEPARTMENT_ID
ORDER BY D.DEP_NAME
```

Example output:

```
 DEP_NAME        | SPENT
    
ACCOUNTING       | 500
CUSTOMER_SERVICE | 400
HRA              | NULL
```

Above query is giving me duplicate data and also I'm not getting the unmatched values.

Can anyone please advise on this?

Comment: Please add sample data and expected result

Comment: If you want all departments regardless of whether they have invoices, you should start with the department table and left join the other tables to it as needed

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
D.DEP_NAME
, SUM(I.SPENT) as 'SPENT'
FROM DEPARTMENT D
LEFT JOIN ROLES R on R.DEPARTMENT_ID = D.DEP_ID 
LEFT JOIN INVOICE I on I.ROLE_ID = R.ROLE_ID
GROUP BY D.DEP_NAME
ORDER BY D.DEP_NAME
```

Since you don't want duplicates you have to group on the department name and take the SUM of the SPENT field from the INVOICE table since you can have multiple invoices per department.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the departments in the output, `Department` table should be the base table in query. This should be the correct query :

```
select D.DEP_NAME, I.SPENT from DEPARTMENT D
left join ROLES R on D.DEP_ID = R.DEPARTMENT_ID
left join Invoice I on R.ROLE_ID = I.ROLEID
```

[SQL Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=8dcbc23901fca4aed06069f57341d353)

Output :

[image]

Comment: He is talking about multiple invoices. Also he mentions he's getting duplicates so he is not grouping correctly and is expecting the sum of the SPENT field from INVOICE table. Check my answer first.